# Nested IF, SUMPRODUCT, SEARCH function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search

Preface: I am NOT a data/excel person

I am trying to search a cell for multiple lists of substrings(?) and return a value if found.

Essentially I want to ask: If the cell contains any of these substrings return "1", if it contains any of these values return "2", if it doesnt contain any return "0"

Here is the formula I have so far:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({"CHF","Asthma","COPD","Congestive","DKA","Ketoacidosis","sickle","stroke"},O2)))))>0,"1", IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({"influenza”,”pneumonia”},O2)))))>0, “2”, “”))
```

The first IF statement works. But when I add the second it says there is an error and I think it has to do with the second SEARCH but not positive.

Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ISNUMBER on the SEARCH
2. you have two different `"`: `“` and `"`.  Then need to all be `"`

---

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"CHF","Asthma","COPD","Congestive","DKA","Ketoacidosis","sickle","stroke"},O2))))>0,1, IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"influenza","pneumonia"},O2))))>0, 2, 0))
```